# SQL-запрос c сортировкой по неделям

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Нужно сделать выборку людей зарегистрировавшиеся за последние полгода, но при этом на выводе нужно получить количество зарегистрированных по неделям

**Сейчас у нас логгируется каждая регистрация, но запрос должен композировать количество регистрациий за 1 неделю и столбцов должно получится за пол года**

Как это выглядит сейчас:

```
01.06.22 => 'Юзер с конкретным ник-неймом',
01.06.22 => 'qwerty123',
01.06.22 => 'user123',
...
03.06.22 => 'u123456'
```

Вывод должен получится примерно такой:

```
01.06.22 => 5000,
08.06.22 => 4500,
15.06.22 => 7800,
22.06.22 => 5200,
29.06.22 => 8100,
05.07.22 => 6600
```

- Во втором примере каждая запись - это количество зарегистрированных пользователей за неделю

Использую DataTime

Comment: Насколько я знаю это делается с помощью DATEDIFF, но я не разобрался как сделать разбиение несколько раз

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php

Comment: А что такое "неделя" в данном конкретном случае? Календарная? 7 дней от начала заданного периода?  Судя по 01.06.22, которое среда - последнее... тогда да, DATEDIFF. И не забыть поделить на 7.

Comment: Недели измеряются с начала периода счета, а не календарная неделя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тестовые данные:

```js
-- create
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  empId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  dept TEXT NOT NULL,
  dd timestamp
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0001, 'Clark', 'Sales', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY));
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0002, 'Dave', 'Accounting', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 DAY));
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0003, 'Ava', 'Sales', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 DAY));

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0004, 'Clark', 'Sales', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 11 DAY));
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0005, 'Dave', 'Accounting', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 13 DAY));
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0006, 'Ava', 'Sales', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 17 DAY));

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0007, 'Clark', 'Sales', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 17 DAY));
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0008, 'Dave', 'Accounting', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 13 DAY));
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0009, 'Ava', 'Sales', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 20 DAY));
```

Запрос, который группирует данные по неделям. Дата - понедельник.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(dd, weekday(dd)), '%d.%m.%y'), count(*) 
from EMPLOYEE
group by DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(dd, weekday(dd)), '%d.%m.%y');
```

Если надо "сдвинуть" дату начала, то запрос должен выглядеть примерно так

```
select DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(dd, weekday(dd) - 3), '%d.%m.%y'), count(*) 
from EMPLOYEE
group by DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(dd, weekday(dd) - 3), '%d.%m.%y');
```

Comment: К сожалению я использую datatime и ваш пример на моей таблице возвращает лишь

`SUBDATE(created_at, weekday(created_at)) 
count(*) 
2023-01-09 23:47:32
1
2023-01-09 23:47:35
1
2023-01-09 23:47:37
1
2023-01-09 23:48:42
1
2023-01-09 23:49:51
1
`
И тд..
Но спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @echocage А что же вы об этом в вопросе не указали?

Comment: Виноват, думал по формату понятно будет. Изменил. Прошу прощения!

Comment: @echocage Обновил ответ. Добавил форматирование дат

Comment: Потрясающе. Спасибо большое, помогло!